# How to make sure the file input is video not anything else in Ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, ajax

I want to make sure the user is uploading video no anything else using ajax I using django in backend and I validated this step in Django but I wanna also valid the `FileInput` is video not anything else, and if this file not video then show alert in error, this javascript include uploading files with progress bar

my javascript code

```
  const file_input_label = document.getElementById('file_input_label')

function input_filename(){
  file_input_label.innerHTML = input.files[0].name;

}


 const uploadForm = document.getElementById('upload-form')
 const input = document.getElementById('formGroupExampleInput2')
 console.log(input)

 const alertBox = document.getElementById('alert-box')
 const imageBox = document.getElementById('image-box')
 const progressBox = document.getElementById('progress-box')
 const canceleBox = document.getElementById('cancel-box')
 const canceleBtn = document.getElementById('cancel-btn')

    

 const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

 // whenever choose th file something happen
 input.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
     progressBox.classList.remove('d-none')
     canceleBox.classList.remove('d-none')

     const img_data = input.files[0]
     const url = URL.createObjectURL(img_data)
     console.log(img_data)

     const fd = new FormData()
     fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf[0].value)
     fd.append('video', img_data)

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: uploadForm.action,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: fd,
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('before')
            alertBox.innerHTML = ""
           // imageBox.innerHTML = ""
       },
        xhr: function() {
           const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', e=>{
             // console.log(e)
             if (e.lengthComputable){
               const percent = e.loaded / e.total * 100
               console.log(percent);
               progressBox.innerHTML =
                                       `<div class="progress">
                                           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: ${percent}%" aria-valuenow=" ${percent}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                         </div>
                                         <p>${percent.toFixed(1)}%</p>`
             }
           })
           canceleBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
             xhr.abort()
             setTimeout(()=>{
                 uploadForm.reset()
                 progressBox.innerHTML = ""
                 alertBox.innerHTML = ""
                 canceleBox.classList.add('d-none')
             }, 1000)
           })
           return xhr
       },
        success: function(response) {
           console.log(response)
           // imageBox.innerHTML = `<img src="${url}" width="300px">`

            // imageBox.innerHTML = `<video class="card" controls src="${url}">`
            alertBox.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Successfully uploaded your video. click upload to upload your video</div>`

        },
        error: function(error){
          console.log(error)
           alertBox.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Ups something went wrong!</div>`
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
     })
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input.addEventListener('change', () => { 
        var filePath = input.value; 
      
        // Allowing file type 
        var allowedTypes =  
                /(\.mp4|\.mkv|\.avi|\.flv)$/i; 
          
        if (!allowedTypes.exec(filePath)) { 
            alert('Invalid file type'); 
            input.value = ''; 
            return false; 
        }
})
```